# Combine window.location.href & document.referrer into a single variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, xregexp

## I need to get the current web page url in a single variable like:

```
var x = window.location.href;
```

But the problem is the script will be used sometimes in **Cross domain Iframe** & sometimes in **same domain**. Since `window.location.href` does not work in Cross domain iframe, so I have tested
`x = document.referrer` for cross domain Iframe(read only) and it worked fine. But I need both option in a single variable so I can use it in url validation with `.match()` method in Javascript.

**I tried to combine like this, but its not working**

```
    var x = window.location.href;
if (typeof(window.location.href) === 'undefined') {
    x = document.referrer;
}
```

**My full codes are here:**

// **Get the url**-This part isn't working

```
var x = window.location.href;
if (typeof(window.location.href) === 'undefined') {
    x = document.referrer;
}
```

// **Url validation**--This part is working fine

```
var y = "zebra";
var rgxp = new RegExp(y, "gi");
if (x.match(rgxp) > -1) {
    alert('Found a zebra in url');
```

---

I don't know is it really possible to combine or not, but otherwise I think I have to repeat this script twice. 1 for cross domain Iframe & a 2nd for the same domain.

I am fairly new in Javascript & got stuck here, so any help and direction would be a lifesaver

Comment: That wouldn't be combining, that is using one or the other. And I don't believe `location.href` will ever be `undefined`. Did you mean to [concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators) the two strings?

Comment: What does `window.location.href` return in situations that you would want to use `document.referrer`? Test it for that.

Comment: Patrick Evans.. Not concatenate actually. I just want to get the current web page url. But sometimes it will be used from cross domain iframe. So I need those 2 option at a single variable

Comment: 5ar window.location.href; does not work in cross domain Iframe. In that case document.referrer will do the same job as window.location.href does

Comment: 5ar window.location.href; does not work in cross domain Iframe.

Comment: @guest271314 it looks simple & easy. Doe's it work? Should I use it like this `var x = window.location.href, document.referrer;` I will let you know if it work.

Comment: Check the result of `typeof(window.location.href)`. like `console.log(typeof(window.location.href))` or `alert(typeof(window.location.href))`. Is it really "undefined"?

Comment: @guest271314 - OP used the word "combine" several times, but doesn't mean that. They want to use `.href` if available, otherwise use `.referrer`.

Comment: @nnnnnn I think you are right, that would be the easiest way. Thanks a lot I will try this direction.